# System.Enum combinations with Flags

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Consider the following enumeration:

```
[System.Flags]
public enum EnumType: int
{
    None = 0,
    Black = 2,
    White = 4,
    Both = Black | White,
    Either = ???, // How would you do this?
}
```

Currently, I have written an extension method:

```
public static bool IsEither (this EnumType type)
{
    return
    (
        ((type & EnumType.Major) == EnumType.Major)
        || ((type & EnumType.Minor) == EnumType.Minor)
    );
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:** As evident from the answers, EnumType.Either has no place inside the enum itself.

Comment: shouldn't `Both` be `Black | White`? The way you implemented it `Both` is `0`.

Comment: Also, `Both` and `Either` seem reduntant in this situation where they are implemented as bit flags.

Comment: @nadirs: That's correct. But they help reduce code branching a lot.

Comment: @nadirs meh - I agree `Either` makes no sense, but in a lot of scenarios common composites of flags can make the code very conveneint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With flags enums, an "any of" check can be generalised to `(value & mask) != 0`, so this is:

```
public static bool IsEither (this EnumType type)
{
    return (type & EnumType.Both) != 0;
}
```

***assuming*** you fix the fact that:

```
Both = Black | White
```

(as `Black & White` is an error, this is zero)

For completeness, an "all of" check can be generalised to `(value & mask) == mask`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm including Both and Either to reduce code branching for an already ugly algorithm. That should do it.

Comment: @RaheelKhan your `Either` enum value makes no sense and should be removed.

Comment: I'm assuming that this statement cannot go inside the enum itself since it refers to a runtime value. Or am I missing something? Enums should allow getters.

Comment: @RaheelKhan indeed it cannot go inside the enum. The debate about whether enums should be richer is a complex one... but right now: they don't allow anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
public enum EnumType
{
    // Stuff
    Either = Black | White
}
```

Comment: That would mean EnumType.Both is also equal to EnumType.Either?

Comment: That is definitely a "both". There is no meaning in a value of "either" (at least, as separate to "both")

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
[System.Flags]
public enum EnumType: int
{
    None = 0,
    Black = 1,
    White = 2,
    Both = Black | White,
    Either = None | Both
}
```

Comment: In this case it would be better to set `None = 1`, `Black = 2` and `White = 4`, so `Either` is actually distinct from `Both`.

Comment: Completly missed that one. Thanks @nadirs for catching it.

Comment: @nadirs `None` should **always** be zero in a flags-enum. For Franky: note that Either and Both have the same value here (at least before your recent edit), and that is inescapable.

Comment: @Marc Gravell Yes I know, I would delete my answer now, but I'm gonna let it stay, so that others don't make the same mistake.

Comment: @MarcGravell of course, I was just pointing out that having two bit-flags with the same value didn't make a lot of sense (that's why I specified "in this case"). I agree that None should be zero.